# Ruta de archivos

Tags: android

Tengo un problema acerca de la ruta de un archivo PDF (al parecer archivos en general), lo que pasa es que cuando selecciono un archivo e intento extraer la ruta `data.getData().getPath()` pero lo que me trae es algo parecido a `/document/acc=2;doc=3417` (es un PDF).

Lo que quisiera es extraer la ruta real del archivo.

Estoy testeando en Android 8.

Comment: Considera agregar tu código tal vez es solo un pequeño problema el que tienes en código, revisa [ask].

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en esta plataforma pero es cierto, pondré le código para la próxima ocasión :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira yo Utilizo esta funcion

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    if(uri != null) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

se utiliza para obtener la ruta real y la utilizas asi mira:

```
 Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
 String filepath = getPath(getActivity(), selectedFile);
```

Comment: Excelente, probaré tu solución. Gracias

Comment: Gracias, utilicé tu código y sí funcionó.

Comment: Excelente Happy coding.